# No contract deployed with the name

Tags: ether

This section is my scripts section.. I am running in this error since 1 day I have searched a lot but couldn't find satisfactory answer.. well I am running in total two errors. But for now only this is showing up,

```
Error: No Contract deployed with name Lottery
    at Object.getContract (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\node_modules\hardhat-deploy-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:447:11)
    at mockKeepers (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\BlockChain\hardhat-lottery\scripts\mockoffchain.js:4:18)
```

The code for the run scripts is below,

```js
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat")

async function mockKeepers() {
  const raffle = await ethers.getContract("Lottery")
  const checkData = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes(""))
  const { upkeepNeeded } = await raffle.callStatic.checkUpkeep(checkData)
  if (upkeepNeeded) {
    const tx = await raffle.performUpkeep(checkData)
    const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)
    const requestId = txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId
    console.log(`Performed upkeep with RequestId: ${requestId}`)
    if (network.config.chainId == 31337) {
      await mockVrf(requestId, raffle)
    }
  } else {
    console.log("No upkeep needed!")
  }
}

async function mockVrf(requestId, raffle) {
  console.log("We on a local network? Ok let's pretend...")
  const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
  await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(requestId, raffle.address)
  console.log("Responded!")
  const recentWinner = await raffle.getRecentWinner()
  console.log(`The winner is: ${recentWinner}`)
}

mockKeepers()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })

module.exports.tags = ["all", "lottery"]
```

Lottery is a contract in my contract and it's deployed too.. but I don't know why this error is comping up to me.
If anyone knows the correct answer then tell me the right way to do so.